# Printing java identifiers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8

I have a Java DTO class, if I want to print the identifiers of the elements of the class what is the best way that can be achieved..
Say, I want to print out userId, ViewName, columns, key, label etc. (Not the values)

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ColumnConfigSetDto {

    @JsonProperty("userId")
    private String userId;
    
    @JsonProperty("viewName")
    private String viewName;
    
    @JsonProperty("columns")
    private List<ColumnConfigDto> columns;
}
```

---

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ColumnConfigDto {

    @JsonProperty("key")
    private String key;
    
    @JsonProperty("label")
    private String label;
    
    @JsonProperty("isVisible")
    private Boolean isVisible;
    
    @JsonProperty("position")
    private Integer position;
    
    @JsonProperty("isSortable")
    private Boolean isSortable;
    
    @JsonProperty("isHideable")
    private Boolean isHideable;
    
}
```

Comment: "print the identifiers"? are you trying to print the value that exists in `@JsonProperty`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Arrays
.stream( ColumnConfigSetDto.class.getDeclaredFields() )
.forEach( System.out :: println )
```

See similar code run live at [IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/IyvaaX).

## Details

To discover at runtime the members of a class, use reflection.

Call [`Class#getDeclaredFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields--) for an array of [`Field`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) objects, each representing a declared member field of your class. Interrogate the `Field` object for its name or type.

```java
for( Field field : ColumnConfigSetDto.class.getDeclaredFields() )
{
    System.out.println(
        field.getName()
    );
}
```

See [tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/TOC.html), free of cost.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get the field names of the Java class? That would be reflection: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html

```
Class clazz = obj.getClass;
Field[] fieldArr = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
```